# how to copy (and paste) objects in Crayon Physics Deluxe level editor?

Tags: crayon-physics-deluxe

When I press `CTRL-v` in the level editor, it will paste a shape from the clipboard.  How do I copy a shape into the clipboard?

[image: pasted shapes in Crayon Physics]

Answer (score 2):

While moving an object (with `CTRL` pressed), press `c` and it will be copied.